# PDF submit button to ActionResult to RedirectToAction

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, fdf

I'm running in to an issue with PDF form submitting and I can't seem to find any help online, hopefully stackoverflow and can help me out.

I have a PDF form that the end-user will download. Once the download link is clicked, I'll dynamically insert a submit button in the PDF. The URL attached to the button points to an ActionResult I created called ProcessSubmit. It accepts 2 parameters, ID and Version.

After the user fills out the form and clicks Submit, I retrieve the FDF data from the Request.InputStream and update the PDF form on the server.

Up to this point everything works fine and dandy.

My issue comes in when I want to return to a page in my MVC project (Index, from the same controller I run ProcessSubmit from).

Different things happen from different scenarios:

Using Chrome to View the PDF:

- Nothing happens

Using Adobe PDF to View the PDF:

- Opens a file located in %APPDATA% (file:///C:/Users/USERNAME/AppData/Local/Temp/acrord32_sbx/A9RD9D8.htm) - This file seems to be a broken version of my login page.

My Code:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Requests the form.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">The identifier.</param>
    /// <param name="version">The version.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public ActionResult RequestForm(Guid id, int version)
    {
        if (ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Url != null)
        {
            var processSubmitUriString =
                Url.Action("ProcessSubmit", "Forms", null, ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Scheme);
            var processSubmitUrl = String.Format("{0}?id={1}&version={2}", processSubmitUriString, id, version);
            var source = _FormsProxy.GetPatientClinicalOrderStream(id, version, processSubmitUrl);
            if (source != null)
            {
                return File(source, "application/pdf", string.Format("YourForm_{0}.pdf", DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyy-HHmmss")));
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Processes the submit.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">The identifier.</param>
    /// <param name="version">The version.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public ActionResult ProcessSubmit(string id, int version)
    {
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream))
        {
            var fdfStream = sr.ReadToEnd();
            var fields = FDFParser.Parse(fdfStream.Replace(">>", ">>\r\n"));
            _FormsProxy.UpdatePatientClinicalOrderFromSubmittedData(new Guid(id), version, fields.Fields);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried tried redirecting with the full url specified? Using return Redirect(url);.

Comment: Which method is called when you redirect to Index? Can you show that method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this. Your submission is coming from a POST from Acrobat, and so that's where the redirect is being sent to. Acrobat doesn't know what to do with a redirect.

What should work is if in your PDF in the click event of the "Submit" button you add an additional line after the code that does the actual submit:

`app.launchURL("http://foo.com/Index/000 (your ID)", true);`

(the "true" will cause Acrobat to open the URL in a new browser window, the default is "false", which loads the URL in Acrobat).

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply. This worked for Adobe, I'm now able to redirect back to my index action. How ever, in Google Chrome, clicking Submit does nothing. Any idea?

Comment: Chrome uses it's own PDF rendering engine. I'd start by looking to make sure Chrome isn't blocking the new window from opening, and then I'd start to look into the Chrome PDF engine docs.

http://www.i-programmer.info/news/136-open-source/7433-google-open-sources-pdf-software-library.html

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142056?hl=en